# symfony simple login page error

Tags: symfony, authentication

I tried to implement simple login page by this tutorial (i'm using symfony 2.4):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Login page is fine. But when im submitting form i've got this error:

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?
```

I search web and tried everything. What's wrong with my configuration ?

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: admin, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: admin, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                default_target_path:  /dashboard/
        login_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            anonymous:  ~
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**routing.yml**

```
login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: AdminSecurityBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `pattern` keywork instead of `path`

```
login_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
     ^------ should be path
```

So you have to modify your `routing.yml` that way

```
login_check:
    path: /login_check
```

Comment: thanks and i made a huge mistake. In config.yml i didn't include security.yml :(